# Hidden file/directory across all operating systems in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, macos, hidden-files

I know how to hide files on each of the three major operating systems individually (Mac, Linux, Windows), but how would you hide a file or directory in Linux across all operating systems? Is it even possible?

Comment: Yes, but there is no way to hide the file in Linux so that it would also appear hidden in Windows as well (and OSX for that matter)?

Comment: In all of those cases the desired result would be the same. In this case on a usb drive sharing between operating systems. I could hide the file individually on each OS, but I'd rather have a solution I could just run on linux.

Comment: In my view, it is up to the operating system at hand to treat a file "hidden" or not. With that said, I would aim at making sure the different operating systems you will involve will treat the desired files/directories as hidden.